# Error trying to crawl with nutch - java.net.UnknownHostException on own local hostname

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, nutch

Trying to crawl with Nutch 1.9 on Centos 6.6.

When trying to initalize my first crawl after following this guide:

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

However, I am getting the following exception when launching:

> Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries. Injector:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: Sparky.LITK: Sparky.LITK: Name or
>   service not known     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:960)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)   at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:324)     at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:380)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)     at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:370) Caused by:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: Sparky.LITK: Name or service not known
>     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
>     at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)     ... 12
>   more

It seems to be trying to crawl the machine's own hostname (Sparky.LITK) which is not what I want it to do, I set up a seed.txt list as per the tutorial, but it stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is as simple as adding your machine's host name to your /etc/hosts file pointing back to your loopback address (127.0.0.1)

I ammended my hosts entry as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 Sparky.LITK
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 Sparky.LITK
```

And it worked!